# Sub-Query doesn't return expected result

Tags: mysql, sql, pdo

I'm trying to get the `season.id` which have the maximum date for a `match`.
The query is this:

```
SELECT s.id AS season_id,
s.name AS season_name,
s.competition_id AS competition_id
FROM competition_seasons s
INNER JOIN competition_rounds r ON r.season_id = s.id
INNER JOIN `match` m ON m.round_id = r.id
WHERE s.competition_id = 89
AND m.datetime = (SELECT MAX(m.datetime) FROM `match` m WHERE m.round_id = r.id)
GROUP BY s.id
```

as you can see I have a table called `competition_seasons` which contains all the seasons available for a competition, on this table I get all the information of the competition, in this case the competition have the id `89`.
Later I get all the `rounds` available for the season of the competition through the table `competition_rounds`, a `match` is played on a `round`, so I use `INNER JOIN` on the `match` table because I need to get only the `rounds` that have `matches`.

The competition `89` have different season with different rounds, the season are for example:

- 2017/2018
- 2016/2017
- 2015/2016

the query should return `2017/2018` because is the last season which have the `match` with the `MAX(m.datetime)` this field indicate when the match is played, a `match` played on the season `2017/2018` means that have a date that can start from year 2017 and end to 2018 (so within the two years of the season).

The result of the query instead is 2011, which have absolutely no sense.

What I did wrong in the query?

competition_seasons

```
| id | name       | competition_id
 1     2017/2018       89
 2     2016/2017       89
 3     2015/2016       89
```

competition_rounds

```
| id | name        | season_id
 1     First           1
 2     Second          1
 3     First           2
 4     Second          2
 5     First           3
```

match

```
|id | datetime           |  round_id
  1   2018-03-08 00:00:0    1
  2   2017-09-10 20:30:0    1
  3   2017-04-18 15:30:0    3
  4   2016-03-08 00:00:0    3
  5   2015-04-08 00:00:0    4
  6   2015-05-08 00:00:0    5
```

expected result: season_id = 1 because the `match` of this season have the field `datetime` greater than the previous seasons.

Comment: Could you provide some sample data and expect result?

Comment: Please provide some data and expected results. Also, what type is the "season" (e.g. `2017/2018`)?

Comment: @D-Shih Check my update please, I added the sample data which describe the type of data and the situation

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm thinking `ORDER BY` and `LIMIT` would work:

```
SELECT s.id AS season_id, s.name AS season_name,
       s.competition_id AS competition_id
FROM competition_seasons s INNER JOIN
     competition_rounds r
     ON r.season_id = s.id INNER JOIN 
     `match` m
     ON m.round_id = r.id
WHERE s.competition_id = 89
ORDER BY m.datetime DESC
LIMIT 1;
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
SELECT s.id AS season_id,
s.name AS season_name,
s.competition_id AS competition_id
FROM competition_seasons s
INNER JOIN competition_rounds r ON r.season_id = s.id
INNER JOIN `match` m ON m.round_id = r.id
WHERE s.competition_id = 89
AND m.datetime = (SELECT MAX(m1.datetime) FROM `match` m1
                  INNER JOIN competition_rounds r1 
                  ON m1.round_id = r1.id
                  INNER JOIN competition_seasons s1
                  ON r1.season_id = s1.id
                  AND s1.competition_id = 89)
```

Comment: this return the same result which I wrote in my question.. 2011

Comment: can you fill the example data for 2011 seasons result?